# for-loop value is treated as character for data table column code in R

Tags: r, for-loop, datatable

Recently I am trying to sum multiple columns (numeric) from `tbl.male` and `tbl.female` to `tbl.total` using for-loop.

However, it seems that the for-loop did recognize the `i` in the for-loop as a character and eventually return an error warning as there is no column in data table as `i`, as expected.

Code:

```
for ( i in c(4:17){
     tbl.total[,i] <- tbl.male[,i] + tbl.female[,i]
}
```

Error warning:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(tbl.female, , i) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'i' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..i]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

I did read the FAQ1.1, it doesn't help me after all. This is my first time asking a question here, many thanks.

Comment: In order to make your question reproducible and thus answerable, we need **minimal**, self-contained code and data so that we are able to reproduce your problem on our machine, please follow these simple guidelines: [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

R allows you to make sum of the selected columns without a loop:

```
i <- 4:17
tbl.total <- tbl.male[,i] + tbl.female[,i]
```

Note that you even don't need to enclose `4:17` into `c(4:17)` - it's already a vector!

The code above makes a new `tbl.total`. If `tbl.total` already exists and you just need to replace existing `i` columns of `tbl.total` with a sum, you can use:

```
i <- 4:17
tbl.total[,i] <- tbl.male[,i] + tbl.female[,i]
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it is much more effective than using for-loop. However, I recently found out that it only can apply on object `"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"` object, instead of `"data.frame"` object (it shows the error warning captured). Is there any solution to apply also on `"data.frame"` object as well?

Comment: @ChrisLau That should work with `data.table` as well! I have just tried it in my R and it works properly with plain `data.table` (both with a new `tbl.total` and with replacing existing `tbl.total`). See code [here](https://paste.sh/XVFaaSSQ#DF4btBfSOhmhyjhw-k-1LSs8) and try it. Maybe there's a problem with your data. What error pops up to you?